# String Index Error

Tags: java, error-handling, stringbuilder

I keep getting an error that states my String index is out of range at String.charAt, PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt, and Driver.main. I don't know what that means exactly.  Also my characters won't append to one line from the stringbuilder class that I already instantiated. I was wondering if maybe that was caused by the String index error or whether it was my fault.

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length=0;
        int MaxNumber=100;
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

        do {
            if (PasswordGenerator.matchLength (length))
                System.out.println("The length of the character is " + length);
            length++;                                     // length is randomly picked
        } while (length < MaxNumber );   // or <100

        int index = 0;
        char f = 0;

        for (int d = 0; d < 127 || ; d++) {
            if  (PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt(f, index))
                d = (char) index;
            char aChar = (char)d;
            password.append(aChar);
            System.out.println("Password is: " + aChar);
            index++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any criticism also needed to fix up my code.. (:

Comment: Please paste the exact error you are getting into your question

Comment: There is not a single String in that code (except for the println). Please also show PasswordGenerator and the exception stack trace you are getting.

Comment: Here's the documentation to the class that is in my folder...http://www.technology.heartland.edu/faculty/todds/csci130/assignments/A5_password/doc/index.html

Comment: sorry, i don't know what you mean by exception stack trace. I'm a beginner and don't know the terminology. I apologize..

Comment: if (PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt(f, idx)) from the code snippet provided the character f is set to 0 is that what you intended? Modify the code snippet so that it can be copied and pasted into an editor ;so that someone can help you easily or publish the project on github.com

Comment: Roland is right. I would suggest that you find out how to write jUnit tests to drive the development of your code.

Comment: This `for (int d = 0; d < 127 || ; d++)` is not valid Java syntax, there should be something after `||`. Also you should never change the value of your loop variable of a `for` loop like you do here: `d = (char) index`.

Comment: Please post all the output that your program generates. Especially the part where it says `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: ...`. Just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error since `idx` will vary between 0 and 127. The password from the `PasswordGenerator` is probably not that long. For example, before you ask whether there is a match at index 57, you must ask if 57 is less than the length of the password.

So your task is to guess the password that the generator saves? Then you should do this:

```
Get to know the length of the password.
For each index from 0 upto but excluding the length:
    Guess the character at that index.
```

Comment: I have the length already..Do you want me to post all my code?

Comment: Well, you don't really *have* the length. You printed it out, but your code in the lower part cannot ask *what's the length?*. It should be able to ask that, so that you can have a loop like this: `for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) { /* guess one character */ }`.